# How can I use to promise to make sure an method runs after it saves?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am opening a PDF but I want to save before the PDF opens. It works but it doesn't have enough time to save everything before the PDF opens.

```
  save = (content) =>  {
    this.props.toggleSaving();
    this.props.setSaveFailedStatus(false);
    this.props.saveContent(content);
    this.props.toggleSaving();
  };


   openPdf = (content) => {
     this.save(content);
    window.open(`${window.location.pathname}/print`, '_blank');
   }
```

LMK what the best approach is? `this.save` is a function that is reused elsewhere.

Comment: What is `this.save`? Does it return a Promise?

Comment: @Paulpro updated

Comment: Which of the functions you are calling are asynchronous?  Which of them either return a promise themselves or accept a callback to notify when they are done.  Without making wild guesses, we can only help you when we know what all your functions actually do, which are asynchronous and how they can notify the caller that they are done.  Promises have no magic by themselves to manage async operations, you have to hook into the existing mechanisms for knowing when async operations are done.  As your question stands now, one can only GUESS how to help you (which Jacob has done in his answer).

Comment: @ZenaMesfin - Did you just disappear?  We asked some clarifying questions and you are not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this function does it thing asynchronously:

```
this.props.saveContent(content);
```

That function ought to have a callback or better yet return a Promise so that you can sequence tasks after it completes.

```
function saveContent(content) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...do save
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Because the function is asynchronous, your `save` function will now also need to be asynchronous, meaning it should return a Promise:

```
save = (content) =>  {
  this.props.toggleSaving();
  this.props.setSaveFailedStatus(false);
  return this.props.saveContent(content)
    .then(() => this.props.toggleSaving());
};
```

...and your `openPdf` function can now wait on `save`'s completion:

```
openPdf = (content) => {
  return this.save(content).then(() => {
    window.open(`${window.location.pathname}/print`, '_blank');
  });
}
```

If your environment or Babel transpiler supports it, you can use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make this more convenient.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for require the OP to actually tell us which of their operations are async and what interface they have for knowing when they are completed than just allowing them to write an incomplete question and guessing how to solve it?  Shouldn't we train folks to write complete questions that don't require guessing.

Comment: I dunno, seems pretty clear from the description that `saveContent` does some asynchronous operations from the question. I don't know how JavaScript would magically do IO without being asynchronous.

Comment: node.js has synchronous I/O.  It could be using `fs.writeFileSync()`. for example.  We have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: "it doesn't have enough time to save everything before the PDF opens"

Comment: So, you have no interest in helping to teach the OP how to write a complete and clear question, I guess?  If all your guesses are correct, they should at least provide the interface to `saveContent()`.  Never mind, you clearly  don't care about this so I'll leave now.  I think it's good for the community when we help educate/teach people how to write good questions that have all the info in them necessary to provide a complete answer that requires no guessing.  AND, a good questioner should not disappear for 3 hours either when there are questions about their question.